# Matlab patch object coordinates

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a patch object in Matlab that represents a racetrack. Is there a way to determine whether a certain x-y coordinate lies inside this patch? I want to be able to detect when a racecar drives off the track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no Matlab implementation of what you're asking that i'm aware of, it wouldn't be too hard to do yourself.

If you're track is a convex hull, then you could use the matlab function convhull() to generate the convex hull of the track. This function returns a list of indices and the area of the convex hull.

i.e. 
[k_track, a_track] = convhull(x_track,y_track).

Then compare this to the convex hull of the set of track points and the vehicle point.

x_new = [x_track x_car]

y_new = [y_track y_car]

[k_new, a_new] = convhull(x_new,y_new)

If the car is inside the track, the convex hulls (and therefore areas) will be the same.

if a_track ~= a_new

car outside of track

else

car inside track

end

Note this relies on the track being a convex hull. If it isn't, you may be able to break it into segments that are and iterate the procedure.